# How to replace anchor text inside aps.net label?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How to Replace anchor tag inner text inside of Asp.net label:

For Example :

```
<asp:Label ID="AER_UI_Exam_MPN_ThreeAttemptsBefore_1" runat="server" Text="Please visist: <a id='google'class='translatetext lblfont' href='https://google.com' target='_blank' style="font-size: 12px;">google</a>" CssClass="lblfont translatetext" Style="font-size: 12px;" />
```

if I will get the id based on class

```
$(".translatetext").each(function () {
var id = this.id;
 dictionary[id] = $("#" + id + "")[0].innerText;
});
```

I am getting both the id but anchor tag is replacing as text not as link. here while debug I found the that for first id -innertext is:`Please visist:google`,
when this inner text is replacing with

```
 "some text"
```

the second id is not found for `anchor`.
how to handle this scenario?

> Result is:        Please visist:google,
>
> Expected Result: :Please visist:[google]

Comment: you just need to wrap the current text with brackets. right?

Comment: no if you see my example asp.net label text inside anchor tag will exists if I replace inner text also result should be same as before (UI should be same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi please try this.

```
  <asp:Label ID="AER_UI_Exam_MPN_ThreeAttemptsBefore_1" runat="server" CssClass="lblfont translatetext" 
            Style="font-size: 12px;"> Please visist: <a id='google'class='translatetext lblfont' href='https://google.com' target='_blank' style="font-size: 12px;">google</a></asp:Label>
```

**Edited :**

First you build the anchor tag in Jquery. Like this.

```
 var myhtml="Please visist: <a id='google' class='translatetext lblfont' href='https://google.com'

 target='_blank' style='font-size: 12px;'>"+some text+"</a>";
```

then assign the above variable to that label.

```
$("#AER_UI_Exam_MPN_ThreeAttemptsBefore_1").html(myhtml);
```

Comment: @ponamani I tried this,it want work for me this the result: Visist कृपया: गूगल but  google should be hyperlink.

Comment: @stpdevi please post your expected output and problem clearly

Comment: @vignesh if you see example  label having anchor. if I get innertext using jquery:$("#" + id + "").innerText;
I am getting total inner text-- Please visist:and anchor tag inner text also so here anchor  text is replacing as text. I need to show as anchor tag.understood?

Comment: Do you want to change the only  anchor tag inner text with hyperlink ?

Comment: no I want change both text but Please visist as text and google is hyperlink got it? see result when I replace with hindi text :Visist कृपया: गूगल

Comment: thank you @PonmaniChinnaswamy not exactly your solution is not worked for me but your suggestion is very much for help ful

Comment: sure @stpdevi.. Which issue you are facing?

Comment: here is the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718321/jquery-tab-is-working-after-replace-outerhtml/36718408#36718408

Answer (score 0):

If you wwant to wrap the text with square bracket, use like this,

```
$(".translatetext").each(function() {
  $(this).text("[" + $(this).text() + "]");
});
```

Comment: hi anoop please read my total question not only excepted result