# jQuery tab is not working after replace outerHTML

Tags: jquery, asp.net

The jQuery tab is not working after replacing outerHTML of div of the following example:
There is no change in outerHTML but still tab change is not working. Why?

When I tried like click is working but HTML is not replacing the tab.

```
     $("#prod5").tabs({
                                create: function (event, ui) {
                                    debugger;
                                    event.target.innerHTML == jqXHR;

                                }

                            });

           function data() {
            var replce = $("#tabs").html();
            $("#tabs").html(replce);      
                    $("#tabs").tabs('refresh');
        }
       <div id="tabs" class="col eleven-cols tabs-tt">
<div class="col three-cols contentfontmedium translatetext" id="prod5">


    <ul class="col three-cols contentfontmedium" id="prod6">

        <li><a href="#tabs-1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">2</a></li>

    </ul>

</div>

<div id="subMenus">
    <div id="tabs-1" class="col eight-cols" style="padding-right: 0%; padding-top: 0%;">
        tab1
    </div>

     <div id="tabs-1" class="col eight-cols" style="padding-right: 0%; padding-top: 0%;">
        tab2
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

I am getting outerHTML using jQuery"

```
  $("#" + id + "")[0].outerHTML;
```

And replacing outerHTML using jQuery

```
 $("#" + id + "")[0].outerHTML = replcetext;
```

but tab change is not working after replace.

Below is outerHTML before replce:

```
        function data() {
            var replce = $("#tabs").html();


            $("#tabs").tabs({
                create: function (event, ui) {
                    debugger;
                    event.target.innerHTML == replce;
                    // $("tabs").replaceWith(jqXHR);
                }

            });


         //   $("#tabs").html(replce.toString());
         //// $('#tabs').tabs('load', $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active'));
         ////   $('#tabs').html($(replce).html());
         //   //  $("#tabs").tabs('refresh');
         //   $("#tab-1").load("");
         //   $("#tab-2").load("");
         //       $("#tabs").tabs().addClass("ui-helper-clearfix");
         //       $("#tabs li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");

         // //  var template = Handlebars.compile(replce);
         //   debugger;
          //  $('#tabs').html(template(data));
        }
```

Comment: What about the selector of `$("a[href=#" + id + "]")[0].outerHTML = replcetext;` ?

Comment: <li><a href="#tabs-3">1</a></li> to get outerhtml is error for that than how can I replce

Comment: It worked for me. Let me know what's the error message?

Comment: Can you post your complete script code??

Comment: hi @lesmian  function data() {
                var replce = $("#tabs").html();
                $("#tabs").html(replce);
            }  tha's my code

Comment: But your html doesn't contain div with id tabs? Do you mean prod5? I tried with prod5 and it works correctly? Can you post all code of your aspx?

Comment: And could you please say exactly what is not working after replace? Does is look different?

Comment: @lesmian after replce tab click is not working

Comment: Please guys can any one help for this issue...

Comment: @stpdevi Can you post full code of your aspx file? Not the one rendered in browser? I feel like you don't shows us whole picture.

Comment: @lesmian I working on example  wait I will edit my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109914/discussion-between-stpdevi-and-lesmian).

Comment: @esmian upto now I tried that code its very small example

Comment: but same issue @lesmian

Answer (score 4):

Put your javascript code within document ready function as below, and at the end of page.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var replce = $("#tabs").html();

    $("#tabs").tabs({
        create: function (event, ui) {
            debugger;
            event.target.innerHTML == replce;
            // $("tabs").replaceWith(jqXHR);
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

So the first solution I proposed was not working. Here is a new one that destroys and recreates the tabs.

In this case I am:

- getting the current settings of the tabs
- destroy the tabs
- change the outerhtml with your method
- then recreate the tabs with the saved settings

```js
var id = 'prod5';
$('#' + id).tabs({
  active: 2
});

function clickme() {
  // save settings
  var options = $('#' + id).tabs("option");
  // destroy tabs
  $('#' + id).tabs('destroy')
    // get outerhtml
  var html = $('#' + id)[0].outerHTML;
  // apply a random change
  html = html.replace(/goo/g, 'zar');
  // replace the outerHTML, thus the entire element
  $('#' + id)[0].outerHTML = html;
  // recreate tabs
  $('#' + id).tabs(options)
}

$('#btnReplace').click(clickme);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"/>
<div class="col three-cols contentfontmedium translatetext" id="prod5">
  <nav class="nav-menu touchAction contentfontmedium contentZoom" id="nav2" style="width:100%;">
    <ul class="col three-cols contentfontmedium" id="prod6">
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-4">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-5">5s</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-6">6
<br />goo</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      Content 1
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      Content 2
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      Content 3
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-4">
      Content 4
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-5">
      Content 5
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-6">
      Content 6
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<button id="btnReplace">
  Replace goo with zar
</button>
```

You can also get the HTML before you destroy the tabs, because jQuery UI Tabs is only adding some attributes to the original content and wraps them in another. In an extreme case, you can replace the outerHTML, then destroy and recreate the tabs, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/evvqqrLf/4/, but it might have some unexpected side effects. Basically this is the code you need:

```
  // create tabs 
  // (you need this in order to restore the state for the replaced element)
  $('#' + id).tabs();
  // destroy tabs
  $('#' + id).tabs('destroy');
  // recreate tabs
  $('#' + id).tabs(options);
```

And of course you need to get the options of the original tabs sometime before you replace the HTML: `var options = $('#' + id).tabs("option");`

And yes, I am aware that calling `.tabs()`, `.tabs('destroy')` and then `.tabs()` again is a little overkill, but I wanted to clean up as much as possible from the original initialization. In case you want to risk it, just use `$('#' + id).tabs(options);`

Answer (score 1):

Once the content is replaced, you need to initialize the plugin again

```
$("#" + id).replaceWith(replcetext).tabs();
```

When you replace the entire html, the plugin related data structures are destroyed, that is why it is not working

Comment: I am initializing the plugin again after my replace code done but still not working      $("#tabs").tabs();

Answer (score 1):

@Stpdevi, Why you are trying outerhtml replace? any reason for this?

Replace the tab name like this.

```
 $('#ui-id-2').html('Tab Name');
```

After replacing the Tab text, refresh the tab.  [refer here.](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-refresh)

```
 $( "#prod5" ).tabs( "refresh" );
```

Comment: hi @ponamani for me html is not working in loop I am eplcing the text $("#" + key + "")[0].outerHTML so I am getting outer html

Comment: tabs('refresh') also not worked in your case?. Check any error in  console.

Comment: He is changing the outerHTML of the entire tabs container, so you cannot refresh the tabs. What he needs is a completely different approach that changes the text in the tabs.

Comment: hi if work html also it ginvg me same error   tab not working after my function completed I calling $( "#prod5" ).tabs( "refresh" ); still not working

Answer (score 1):

if your using the selector for id (#id) there isn't need to indicate the first element found

Instead of

```
$("#" + id + "")[0]
```

use

```
$("#" + id + "")
```

And to assign HTML content use

```
$("#" + id + "").html("<div>example</div>")
```

hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

You can try another options, such as handlebar js to generate the html

I might misunderstand your question.
I think "Arun P Johny's" answer might work.

Suppose that you just wanna change the tab title and content.
you can use beforeActivate event,

the following is the html code

```js
 $(function () {
            initTabs();
        });

        function initTabs() {


            var tabContent = $("#divInitial").html();
            $("#tabs").tabs({
                create: function (event, ui) {
                   // here is your original example, the tab's structure will be destroy
                   // event.target.innerHTML = tabContent; // that is main content

                },
                beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
                    var tabIndex = ui.newTab.index(); // get tab index:JQuery UI 1.9 or later
                    var content = $("#divContentToBeReplace").html();
                    $("#fragment-" + parseInt(tabIndex + 1)).html("tab" + parseInt(tabIndex + 1) + content); // Change Tab content
                    var title = $("#tabs ul li").eq(tabIndex).text();                 
                    $('#tabs ul li:nth-child(' + parseInt(tabIndex + 1) + ') a').text('Other text'); //Change Tab title
                }
            });
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#fragment-1">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-2">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-3">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="fragment-1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
        <div id="fragment-2">
            tab2 contents
        </div>
        <div id="fragment-3">
            tab3 contents
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="divContentToBeReplace" style="display:none">
       contents data changed.
    </div>

    <div id="divInitial" style="display:none">
        init
    </div>
```

Comment: can you give me example

Comment: is jquery librays?